# Chinese Text to Speech in iOS

Tags: ios, text-to-speech

Does anyone know how to implement Text to Speech with Chinese language in iOS?

Any links or suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: I don't think there is an api for that yet...

Answer (score 2):

As Sten said, you could use [iSpeech](http://www.ispeech.org/). Here is the same answer, in more detail:

You can use their [API](http://www.ispeech.org/developers), but the problem with that is that it is limited to 200 uses/day.

If you want to have unlimited uses, you need to buy it. One way to get around that is to access the data returned by their [demo program](http://www.ispeech.org/text.to.speech.demo.php) (which returns in mp3 format).

I made a small piece of code that demonstrates that in Python. Python is available for iOS from [this](http://pythonforios.com/) site. The demo program has a limit of 20 words a go, so your program must split every 20 words, and feed the segments in separately. The following code does not use a buffer, so there might be a slight delay between segments.

```
from urllib import quote_plus

def speak(text): 
    import pydshow 
    words = text.split() 
    temp = [] 
    stuff = [] 
    while words: 
        temp.append(words.pop(0)) 
        if len(temp) == 24: 
            stuff.append(' '.join(temp)) 
            temp = [] 
    stuff.append(' '.join(temp)) 
    for i in stuff: 
        pydshow.PlayFileWait('http://api.ispeech.org/api/rest?apikey=8d1e2e5d3909929860aede288d6b974e&format=mp3&action=convert&voice=chchinesemale&text='+quote_plus(i))

if __name__ == '__main__':
       speak('Hello. This is a text-to speech test.')
```

I find this ideal because the demo program DOES use the API, but it uses the API key that is used for the demo program. Therefore, it never runs out. The key is `8d1e2e5d3909929860aede288d6b974e`. Also, the program is quite simple, and may be adapted to work in any programming language.

You can actually test this at work without the program, by typing the following into your address bar:

http://api.ispeech.org/api/rest?apikey=8d1e2e5d3909929860aede288d6b974e&format=mp3&action=convert&voice=chchinesemale&text=Hello

Here is how you can tailor that to your needs:

```
http://api.ispeech.org/api/rest?apikey=8d1e2e5d3909929860aede288d6b974e&format=mp3&action=convert&voice=chchinesemale&text=
```

Followed by the text you want to speak. You can also adjust the gender, by changing, in this case, the `chchinesemale` to something else that iSpeech offers. For example, `chchinesefemale`. This will speak the same text, but in a feminine voice. Specifications on the codes can be found [here](http://www.ispeech.org/downloads/ispeech-api-guide-2011-12-12.pdf).

Hope I helped!

NOTE: Pydshow is my wrapper around DirectShow, which is Windows-only. You have to find an alternative to it for iOS if you choose this method.

Answer (score 1):

iSpeech can handle Chinese, is free for shorter messages and works well. The voice rendered online however, so you need a connection. You can test the voice [here](http://www.ispeech.org/text.to.speech.demo.php):